# Will practicing casting on my backyard lawn damage my fly line? If so, how to avoid it?

Tags: fishing-tackle, fly-fishing, casting

I have been practicing fly casting in my backyard using the same line that I use to fish. The question is: will my line get damaged from this? I reckon that these things are made to drag through water and vegetation, but I'm still worried that me dragging it through my lawn will accelerate the wear and tear process. Should I use an old line for that? Is there any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fly lines have [special coatings](http://globalflyfisher.com/fishbetter/flylines/) that help you cast and manage the line on/in the water. Under ideal conditions you would use an older line for practice on the land because repeated contact with the ground, vegetation, sticks, etc. will damage your line:

1. Rough spots will not shoot through guides as smoothly as unblemished line. This will have a negative impact on the distance you can cast.
2. A rough line will experience more turbulence moving through the air. This will also have a negative effect on the distance, and possibly on accuracy of your cast.
3. If the coating of a floating line gets damaged enough, it can permit water to soak the braided core. This can cause the floating line to sink - or at least not float as well. Aside from the obvious fact that it will no longer be floating, the line will also be more difficult to pick up off the water to cast.

[Cleaning a flyline](http://www.rioproducts.com/fishing-tips/cleaning-fly-lines/) can help mitigate some of these effects, but it is very difficult to dry out the core once it is wet.

Answer (score 1):

When I first began fly fishing I learned in the parking lot of Bass Pro Shops (free weekend class).  After that, I went home and practiced in an empty field.  After practicing for a while I replaced the tippet but never touched the fly line itself.

Of course, YMMV - but that's my experience

Comment: My experience matches this.

Comment: Love those down votes without reason why - especially with empirical evidence to back my claim.